# How to access a parent activity from a child one in WF4

Tags: workflow-foundation

How can I access a parent activity from a child activity in WF4? In older versions there was Parent property but it doesn't exist anymore.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try passing in the parent activity as a parameter?

Comment: No. Is this possible (in designer)? I couldn't find a way to refer to the current composite activity in an expression entered to initialise a parameter in a designer.

But I found a workaround. What I actually needed was workflow id and this can be retrieved from the execution context of any activity.